# CoordinatorLayout with two floating action buttons

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

I have two Fabs located inside a CoordinateLayout view. When I show a Snackbar, I expect the two Fabs go up all together, but the result is that only one of the Fab (lower one) responds and go up (see picture). what do I miss here?

berfore [image]
after [image]

Calling snack bar

```
 mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coords_wrapper), "Loading", 1000000000);
```

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coords_wrapper">

    <!-- main contents here, left out -->
    <Relativelayout ...... />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_button_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src ="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_button_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src ="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per the fab's `Behavior`, it translates only if it would intersect the snackbar otherwise. The top button clearly doesn't collide with the snackbar, so nothing happens.

You could try defining an anchor:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_button_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_anchor="@id/action_button_filter"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_button_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src ="@drawable/ic_add_black"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    />
```

This will the determine a relation between the top fab (`action_button_location`) and the bottom fab (`action_button_filter`), so that the first always stays on top of the other, as defined with `layout_anchorGravity` and `layout_gravity` attribute, both set to `top`. You might need to redefine your margins.

Comment: I think action_button_filter needs to be defined before action_button_location to be able to use it as anchor. Also, I needed to use anchorGravity right|top. And include layout_marginBottom="82dp" (to avoid having them touching each other)